# No authorization dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication, canvas, authorization

How can I make a Facebook app that doesn't require users to log in/authorize my app? Is it even possible for canvas apps?

The conversion in auth dialog is quite poor (39%) for my app, even though I ask for the basic information only. Hence the question.

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special actions necessary to run a canvas app in Facebook without authentication. Simply set the **Canvas URL** and **Secure Canvas URL** in your app's settings (`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/summary`) and it should just work.

Keep in mind that you cannot access any of the useful functionality Facebook offers if you forego authentication. You'll be missing out on:

- The **Invite Friends** dialog
- Creating notifications
- Retrieving a user's friend list and information
- Etc.

In fact, if you're not leveraging any of the available functionality Facebook provides, there's no sense in even creating a canvas app. You might as well enjoy the benefits of using the entire window for your application and host it standalone.

Comment: But it means that I won't be able to get even the fbid of the user, right?

Comment: That's correct. You can request a user's name, gender, and fbid by simply querying the graph by username or id (eg: http://graph.facebook.com/648900111 or http://graph.facebook.com/thinkswan), but you need to know exactly who you're looking for beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon what you're doing with your app.

- If you app uses features that requires login, then yes, you will need to get each user to log in.
- If your app doesn't use features of the API that require login, then don't use it.

There's many social plugins that can accomplish a lot of what many people look for and most all of them don't require a login.